# Setting Text on a Path

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, geometry

Using LuaLaTeX, I want to create an effect where text begins as a footnote but curves upward and ends up in front of the body text.

Sort of hard to describe, but picture the body text ending prematurely on a page (with full pages of body text preceding and after it) and the footnote text tilting upward on a path to eventually "become" the rest of the body text.

Is this something that can only be achieved via something like TikZ, or could I hack the geometry settings for this particular page to achieve it?

Sorry, no MWE here because I don't know where to start.

Comment: I understand the value of a MWE in nearly all situations, but it would be a little silly here since I have no clue what to do. I need text to flow from the footnote frame to the body text frame, through the space in between, and haven't the foggiest idea how to do that.

Comment: Can you please do a mockup using some graphic tool or even plain pencil and paper? I'm having problems picturing your description.

Comment: You could at least provide the framework of the document, including some pseudo-text in the body and footnote so that people don't have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 8):

Is this sort of what you want? I tweaked manually but should be doable if you know what you are doing with the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,kantlipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
Then some more text finishing randomly on the sentence in the next line and I placed a tikzmark 
right HERE\tikzmark{a}\footnote{Also one tikzmark HERE\protect\tikzmark{b}} \hspace{3.5em} and 
continue here% 
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[
    decoration={text along path,
    text={
        Some long text along a long curve that 
        I'm hoping that it would be long enough to meet the line, merge
        }
    },decorate] (pic cs:b) to[in=180,out=0] ([xshift=5em]pic cs:a);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you, and for anyone confused by my description, this is exactly what I was going for.

Comment: `+1` Sir, your text is escaping! `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I was working in a solution using the same ideas than percusse, but he was faster. Nevertheless, I understood a different layout, so I'm posting here too.

As in percusse's solution, the "curved text" cannot be arbitrary. It has to have the precise length to fill the curve length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1-2]
\tikzmark{last paragraph}
\footnote{\lipsum*[3]\tikzmark{last footnote line}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, decoration={text along path,
            text={
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Vestibulum ultricies sollicitudin iaculis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus.
    }}]
    \footnotesize
    \coordinate (right margin) at ($(current page.east)-(1in,0)$);
    \draw[decorate, rounded corners=1cm]
       (last footnote line) -- (last footnote line-|right margin) |- (last paragraph);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you, this is also a good solution. Commenting to confirm that this and percusse's answers are perfectly in line with what I was trying to describe.